# How can I create a variable for just the Size, Used, and Available of df?

Tags: shell, df

Say I want to create variables, one for each the size, used, and available when using df. How can I create variables for each? Is there an option that returns just one of these things?

```
directorySize=

directoryUsed=

directoryAvailable=
```

Say I want to create those variables based on the home directory. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There's no option to just return one field. However, the option `-P` guarantees that all the fields are printed on the same line (without this option, if the first column is too wide, the others are shifted to the next line). You can then use awk to print the desired column from the second line.

```
size=$(df -Pk ~ | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}')  # in kB
```

To set all the variables at once, you can make awk print a shell snippet.

```
eval "$(df -Pk ~ | awk 'NR==2 {printf "size=%d used=%d available=%d", $2, $3, $4}')"
```

A few exotic systems allow spaces in filesystem labels, which make reliable parsing of the `df` output impossible. Unfortunately, there's no other portable way.

On Linux only, you can use the `stat` command. This is a bit clumsy the sizes are expressed in blocks.

```
block_size=$(stat -f -c %S ~)
total_blocks=$(stat -f -c %b ~)
free_blocks=$(stat -f -c %f ~)
size=$((block_size * total_blocks)) # in bytes
available=$((block_size * free_blocks))
used=$((size - available))
```